# Grammar checking API?

Tags: php, api, grammar

Are there any APIs that check the grammar of a given string?

If so can you give examples?

Comment: [Perfect Tense](https://www.perfecttense.com/developers) has an API that can check for both spelling and grammar mistakes. They have a [PHP SDK](https://github.com/PerfectTense/pt-client-php) with examples that you can use.

Comment: GrammarBot has a free grammar checking API that also corrects spelling mistakes.  [Grammar Bot Quickstart](https://grammarbot.io/quickstart)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the Deadline does exactly what I need.

http://www.afterthedeadline.com

It works really well, most of the time. But it does miss some common grammar mistakes (e.g. your/you're, their/there/they're, subject-verb agreement problems, etc.).

Comment: So why not simply use afterthedeadline?